# Binary search a list of values with decimals and normal integers

Tags: java, binary-search

```
{
public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
public static int binarySearch(Integer[] a, int x)
{
    int low=0;
    int high = a.length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (a[mid].compareTo(x)<0)
        low = mid + 1;
        else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0)
        high = mid - 1;
        else 
        return mid;
    }
    return NOT_FOUND;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int SIZE = 8;
    Integer[] a = {-3,10,5,24,18.5,10.5};
    System.out.println("18.5 found at " +binarySearch(a, 18.5));
}
```

How do I make it so the decimal numbers, 18.5 and 10.5 don't ruin the program? I understand that Integer[] a can't work with the decimals, but I don't know if I need another list, Integer with the regular numbers, and float with the decimals. If so I'm not sure how to create two lists like that either. Thanks for any help

Comment: Now's probably a good time to [read up on how floating point numbers are represented](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/), because you may run into some problems if you try to look up a floating point number.

Comment: hmm, probably no use of doing binary search on a non-ordered list!!!

Comment: Just change int/Integer to float or double? It seems fairly trivial, especially given that you already seem to know you're supposed to use float. Why do you want 2 lists? You can do it with 2 lists if you really want, but that seems like something you need to figure out the logic for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows you to pass an array of say Integer or Double to a method that expects an array of [Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) objects.

Therefore *one* simple solution would be to change your search method accept Number objects - to then call its `doubleValue()` method when comparing values. And when you now pass *either* an array of Integer objects (that only contains whole numbers), or an array of Double objects (which could be floating point or whole numbers), the *same* processing can take place.

But of course: the whole thing *can* only work when your list is ordered ( in your example it is **not** ).